# Can I establish my wireless connection using Ubuntu 20.04 on a thumb drive?

Tags: networking, wireless

I have successfully created a Ubuntu 20.04.1 bootable thumb drive using my MacBook Pro. I don’t want to install on my HD just yet. I am unable to locate my wireless network. The menu in the upper right hand corner only displays an option for wired connection. I guess that my question is do I have to install it on my Mac for Ubuntu to provide a wireless option?

Comment: No, it means that you wireless hardware likely WON'T be recognized by a proper install without a bit of extra work. You can do the same process on the Live image (it just won't be saved).

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -k`